# Google assistant not responding in windows

Tags: grpc, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I tried installing google assistant in Windows 10 and had my device registered. But when I run the assistant and ask it a question, it responds

> "ERROR:grpc._channel:Exception iterating requests!"

I have included a screenshot of the long error message as well. Any suggestions?

Screenshot of error response:

[image]